# Date in database is considered as String in front-end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, momentjs

I want to save a `date` item in my database for logs of my website:

```
var LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: Date,
    ... ...
})
```

To generate and save a log in the back-end:

```
log.date = new Date()
console.log(log.date.getTime()) // it works well
log.save(...)
```

When I check the database in mongo, it shows: `"date" : ISODate("2017-12-02T01:51:44.540Z")`.

However, in the front-end, when i want to read the log, `log.date.getTime()` gives an error `TypeError: log.date.getTime is not a function`. It seems that `log.date` is considered as a `String` rather than a `Date`.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up a JavaScript Date object with an ISO Date string. When you save to the database, it does become a string. You have to convert the date string back into a javascript date object before you can use the getTime() method. Try:

```
var myDate = new Date(dateStringFromDatabase);
console.log(myDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Is it possible to save a JavaScript Date object into the database? I tried `var LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ date: Object })`, it still saves an ISO Date string.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If it is possible, it might become difficult to query based on dates if they're stored in an unusual way.